# How to access files checked out by another workflow in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Can I access the files that are checked out or generated by a [caller/called workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows)?

I want to have a separate *setup.yml* workflow that checks out the repository code and then reuse that workflow in other workflows.

Here is an example called workflow file (*setup.yml*):

```yaml
name: Set the project up
on: workflow_call

jobs:
  setup:
    name: Set the project up
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'
```

Here is the caller workflow file (*ci.yml*):

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  setup:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/setup.yml

  test-the-project:
    needs: setup
    uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yml
```

Comment: You won't able to do it that way, because each job run on a new runner (VM). What you perform in the setup job would need to be performed on the test-the-project job. What you could eventually is to use a reusable workflow or a composite actions instead, and use it as the first step of the job performing your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if the caller workflow has the steps that you want to perform implicit.

First, you don't need to checkout the code when install node. Then put the content of the jobs of test.yml as differents jobs inside of ci.yml.

For exmaple:

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  setup:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/setup.yml

  test-the-project:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Check Node version and install
      run: node -v && npm i
```